# How to let slurm limit memory per node

Tags: slurm

Slurm manages a cluster with 8core/64GB ram and 16core/128GB ram nodes.
There is a low-priority "long" partition and a high-priority "short" partition.
Jobs running in the long partition can be suspended by jobs in the short partition, in which case pages from the suspended job get mostly pushed to swap. (Swap usage is intended for this purpose only, not for active jobs.)

How can I configure in slurm the total amount of RAM+swap available in each node for jobs?

There is the `MaxMemPerNode` parameter, but that is a partition property and thus cannot accommodate different values for different nodes in the partition.

There is the `MaxMemPerCPU` parameter, but that prevents low-memory jobs to share unused memory with big-memory jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the memory of each node using the `RealMemory` parameter in the node definition (see the [slurm.conf manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html))

Comment: The way I understand it is that RealMemory does not include swap.  Slurmd determines this value dynamically if not set in slurm.conf. It does not accept a setting higher than the amount of real memory available in the node.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The slurm.conf man page says that `FastSchedule` set to 2 is generally useful only for testing purposes but this seems to be a good solution anyway.