# Slurm uses more memory than allocated

Tags: slurm, job-scheduling

As you can see in the picture below, I have made a sbatch script so that 10 job array (with 1GB of memory allocation) to be run. However, when I run it as the second picture shows, the memory used is 3.7% of total memory, which equates to about 18.9GB per job... Could anyone explain why this is happening?
(I did `sbatch --nodelist node1 ver_5_FINAL_array_bash` on the linux terminal )
Thank you!
[image]

For reference, the picture below shows that the amount of allocated memory is indeed 10GB, as specified in the `sbatch` script

Possibly pertinent information: our servers use both slurm and regular job submissions (without any job submission methods like slurm)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `--mem` option gives the minimum memory requirement (see the documentation here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_mem)

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, I can't see how that answers my question.. I specifeid --mem to be 1GB on the SBATCH script, and also the default memory settings on our slurm is 100MB per cpu.

Comment: These are the minimum memory requirements, so you would need to adjust your config to lower the maximum memory in order to force limits on memory usage (see https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_RealMemory and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002719/how-to-let-slurm-limit-memory-per-node). This may not be desirable

Answer (score 0):

A hard limit can by set by the Slurm administrator, by using [cgroups](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroups.html). It's not something the user can do, I don't think.

A cgroup is created for the job with hard resource limits (CPU, memory, disk, etc), and if the job exceeds any of these limits, the job is terminated.